# Excel.. using INDEX and MATCH to find a string in duplicate values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need a formula in Sheet1!C2, maybe a combination of INDEX and MATCH to find out, using ID field as a key, if a certain ID bought screws (sheet 2).
My problems are: ID is duplicated in sheet 2, sometimes the purchase is written as `*screw*` or `*screws*` (is it possible to use `*screw*` in a formula combination INDEX and MATCH)?

[image]

Comment: welcome at superuser. please do the effort at least to type your question here, instead of just posting a picture! what do you mean by `CORRESP`, there is no such a formula in Excel. Why do you think those would be the right functions? please share what have your researched / tried so far.

Comment: I am sorry: CORRESP (function in portuguese) = MATCH function in English

Comment: Probably going to need some sort of `sumproduct` here

Comment: Thanks for your comment 
I don’t need to do any type of calculations like sum or sumproduct, just need to know if a certain ID bought screw or screws

Comment: This is what I unsuccessfully tried in my excel workbook
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$C$5,MATCH(A2&”*screw*”, INFORMATION in sheet 2,0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is with a helper column on sheet 2.  In C2:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("screw",LOWER(B2))),"",A2)
```

You have screw capitalized in some cases, so LOWER compares it to the lowercase version of B2.  If you might look for other items, store screw in a cell somewhere as an entry value and use a reference to that cell instead of hard coding it in the formula.  If B2 contains screw, it stores the ID from column A.  Otherwise it leaves the cell blank.  Copy this down the column as needed.  So column C contains the ID for any row where B contains "screw".

[image: sheet2]

On sheet 1, cell C2 would contain:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,Sheet2!C:C,0)),"NO","YES")
```

Copy that down the column as needed.  For each row, it looks for an exact match of the ID in column C of sheet 2.  If it finds it, you get a "YES"; otherwise, "NO".

[image: sheet1]

Comment: Fixer1234 That Was Perfect!
My real Excel table has 75.000 lines and your solution is going to save me a lot of time
Was apprehensive about the translation English – Portuguese, but the formulas work just impeccably:
=SE(É.ERRO(LOCALIZAR("parafuso";MINÚSCULAS(B2)));"";E2)
=SE(É.ERRO(CORRESP(A2;Siag!C2:C:C;0));"NÃO";"SIM")
Thank you very much

Comment: Your solution is even better that I initial thought!!!

“If you might look for other items, store screw in a cell somewhere as an entry value and use a reference to that cell instead of hard coding it in the formula”

Thanks again